# How to remove hacks from my account?

Tags: payday-2

I recently re-downloaded Payday 2 to play with some friends who bought in during the summer sale. The commented that I was able to run much faster than they were even when they were sprinting. We did some testing and found I must have some hack on my account.

I vaguely remember playing with a hacker the last time I had it downloaded and ended up with a few issues that I got sorted.

Is there a simple way to remove hacks? I’d like to enjoy the game how it’s meant to be played.

Comment: Playing with someone who has cheating software installed can in no way transfer their cheating software to you.

Answer (score 3):

These aren't hacks at all from what I can tell. Armor slows you down and certain skills make you go faster. You could just have a faster build than your friends.

If you and your friends had the same armor and skills on then I don't know what you could do unless you know what type of hack you have installed. You could delete all your files and re-download the game but you'd lose all of your progress.

Comment: That’s what I thought would be the case but a lot of weird stuff happened that session that affected my character. Extra move speed and ton more cash. I didn’t know if overkill had a server side vulnerability that would allow for transfer

Comment: @Robbie one thing to note is that hackers can make permanent changes to your game so I wouldn't rule out these kinds of changes entirely. Some changes, such as giving experience, cards, or cash cannot be returned once they're added to your account without resetting your profile- even by an external party. I can't explain the differences in speed, however. That seems likely due to in-game mechanics.

Comment: Well then the only way it seems like he can fix his account is by resetting his account unless the armor or skills is the actual cause. Seems really dumb that playing with a hacker can permanently screw you.

Comment: PD2 supports Steam Cloud, so as long as that's enabled and properly synched before uninstalling it will be fine.

Comment: If he synched he would save whatever hacks he has though.

Answer (score 3):

"Hacks" or cheats in Payday 2 use the Lua hook/injector, [BLT](https://github.com/JamesWilko/Payday-2-BLT) or its more updated fork, [SuperBLT](https://superblt.znix.xyz/). Non-cheating Lua mods also use this Lua hook. To uninstall it, go to the `\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2` directory and look for files named *IPHLPAPI.dll* or *WSOCK32.dll*. Delete them if they exist. This will uninstall BLT or SuperBLT, and any mods dependent on them will not run anymore. You may also delete the '*mods*' folder, also in that directory. That contains the BLT/SuperBLT mods.

If those files do not exist, then there are no "hacks" or Lua mods installed in your game. The movement speed differences can be explained by the game's mechanics on the different [skills](https://payday.fandom.com/wiki/Skills) or [perk decks](https://payday.fandom.com/wiki/Perk_Decks) or [armors](https://payday.fandom.com/wiki/Armors). Certain skills or perk decks modify your movement speed. And the "heavier" the armor you wear, the slower you'll be. A player wearing a Two-Piece Suit will move much faster than someone wearing an Improved Combined Tactical Vest.

Outside of that, if you notice unusual behavior not explained by the game mechanics, then it might be because of BLT mods used by the other people you're playing with. For example, a cheating host can spawn a lot of bags giving all other players in the lobby lots of cash and experience for finishing a mission. Another user can also use a mod to slow down other players as if their game is in slow motion.